# Why are these scalacheck recursive generators not equivalent?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

While trying to learn the ScalaCheck tool, I wrote two versions of a Map generator (I know there is one of these built in, but this was an exercise).

It seems that `genMap0` and `genMap00` should be equivalent, and `genMap00` is bit cleaner, but in fact `genMap0` works, but `genMap00` fails miserably.

The `yield` is adorned with a `println` that can be turned on to see what happening (just edit the `speak` method), but even with this information I cannot say I really understand why the difference. This makes me think that another generator I try to write may also be flawed.

Can someone give a nice explanation of what is different between `genMap0` and `genMap00`?

```
  import org.scalacheck._
  import Arbitrary._
  import Gen._
  import Prop._

  def speak(message: String): Unit = if (false) println(message)

  lazy val genMap0: Gen[Map[Int, Int]] = for {
    k <- arbitrary[Int]
    v <- arbitrary[Int]
    b <- arbitrary[Boolean]
    m <- if (b) value(Map.empty[Int, Int]) else genMap0
  } yield if (b) {
    speak("false"); m
  } else {
    speak("true"); m.updated(k, v)
  }

  lazy val genMap00: Gen[Map[Int, Int]] = for {
    k <- arbitrary[Int]
    v <- arbitrary[Int]
    m <- oneOf(Map.empty[Int, Int], genMap00)
  } yield if (m.isEmpty) {
    speak("empty:" + m); m
  } else {
    speak("not empty:" + m); m.updated(k, v)
  }

  val n = 5
  for (i <- 1 to n; m <- genMap0.sample) println(m)
  println("--------------")
  for (i <- 1 to n; m <- genMap00.sample) println(m)
```

This is the output (`genMap00` always generates the empty map):

```
scala -cp scalacheck_2.10-1.10.1.jar
...
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

Map()
Map(1 -> 1, 1530546613 -> -1889740266, -187647534 -> 0)
Map()
Map(-1 -> 2039603804)
Map(646468221 -> 1)
--------------
Map()
Map()
Map()
Map()
Map()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem the recursive generation always starts with an empty map, so `gen00` always ends up with a generator that produces an empty map. The problem is the empty condition is also being used to detect termination.

This is fixed by `gen000`:

```
  lazy val genMap000: Gen[Map[Int, Int]] = for {
    k <- arbitrary[Int]
    v <- arbitrary[Int]
    m <- oneOf(None, genMap000.map(g => Some(g)))
  } yield (for (x <- m) yield x.updated(k, v)).getOrElse(Map())
```

This uses an intermediate `Option[Map]`, with the `None` state indicating termination.

Using the explicit `Boolean` generator appears to be cleaner.